# Modify external SWF with actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, hide, actionscript-2, movieclip

How can I load an external SWF from a URL, and then hide a movieclip in it?

The version of actionscript to achive this doesn't matter, it can be 2, 3, or even 1 for that matter.

I've tried using this (actionscript 3), but it doesn't work:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://test.com/room.swf"); 
var room:Loader = new Loader() 
room.load(request); 
addChild(room);
this.triggers_mc.alpha = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://test.com/room.swf"); 
var room:Loader = new Loader() 
room.load(request); 
room.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSWFComplete);
addChild(room);

function onSWFComplete(e:Event):void {
    room.triggers_mc.alpha = 0;
}
```

You need to wait for the external SWF to load in order to interact with it. By adding the    `Event.COMPLETE` to it you are waiting for the SWF to load and after that setting the `alpha` to 0.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but I get an error that says `Scene 1, Layer 'action', Frame 1, Line 8 1119: Access of possibly undefined property triggers_mc through a reference with static type flash.display:Loader.` when I do that.

Comment: Seems like there is no MovieClip with that name in your External SWF. Are you sure it has that name?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary try this